# When will TLS 1.2 be deprecated?

Tags: tls

Just wondering where I can track TLS 1.2, specifically, when will it be deprecated?  A link would be appreciated - thanks!

Comment: There is no fixed date and every application/library gets to decide when to remove support. This includes browsers, some of which still allow TLS 1.0 (table of support by browser version  in the [wiki page for TLS](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security)). But note that a given TLS version being supported does not mean all ciphers and features.

Answer (score 6):

**2023 edit:** @BrunoRohée points out in the comments:

> TLS 1.0 and 1.1 were deprecated by IETF in RFC 8996
> datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc8996 in March 2021. AFAIK there is no plan
> to deprecate TLS 1.2 yet but a bunch of the ciphersuites it supports
> are deprecated.

**Original answer:**
According to a quick internet search, TLS versions 1.0 and 1.1 were not formally deprecated (unlike SSL [2.0](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6176) and [3.0](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7568)), but rather were declared deprecated by [several large internet](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2018/10/browser-vendors-unite-to-end-support-for-20-year-old-tls-1-0/) companies in order to force other vendors to stop using them.

[Here](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc5246/) appears to be a tracker, but as you may see it does not show 1.0 or 1.1 as deprecated. This type of news would likely be covered on news sites and blogs by major companies well in advance of such a change.

Comment: There's an ongoing effort by the IETF TLS working group to more officially deprecate TLS versions 1.0 and 1.1 (see [_"Deprecating TLSv1.0 and TLSv1.1"_](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-ietf-tls-oldversions-deprecate/), still undergoing revisions as of 2020-07-27) at least as a best current practice, if not as a complete formal deprecation.

Comment: Also, the tracker you linked is for the RFC 5246 standardisation process. That's the standard that describes the TLS 1.2 protocol. It doesn't contain any timeline information about deprecation of TLS 1.2, nor the deprecation of TLS 1.0 or 1.1. It's also important to distinguish between _obsoletion_ and _deprecation_, in terms of how the IETF designates standards. An obsolete standard just means there's a newer standard that replaces it (e.g. TLS 1.3 obsoletes TLS 1.2). You are still free to use the older standard. A deprecated standard (e.g. SSLv3) should not be used any more.

Comment: This question still gets high ranking in search engines so we might as well have the most up to date information TLS 1.0 and 1.1 were deprecated by IETF in RFC 8996 
 https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc8996/ in March 2021. AFAIK there is no plan to deprecate TLS 1.2 yet but a bunch of the ciphersuites it supports are deprecated...